# javascript code executing only on chrome, but not on firefox or IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, prototypejs

can anyone tell me why the following code

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function () {
    if($('my_var').value=="my_value"){
     alert('some message');
    }
});
```

executes on Chrome, but not on Firefox or IE?

does it matter that in the same script,  i also have a  `window.onload = function loaded() {..}`  block ?

Comment: I don't think setting `window.onload` should be a problem, unless that function runs before other event handlers and also calls `event.stop()`.  If you suspect it is a problem then you should try removing that to see what happens.

Comment: can you confirm that the `dom:loaded` event is being fired, either an `alert()` to `console.log()` will do that, - if the event is fired then the `$('my_var').value=="my_value"` is not evaluating to `true` in IE/Firefox